# Sending custom emails in Magento2.1

Tags: magento2, email-templates, email-translation

I am creating a new module for inquiry submission. After form is submitted my control comes on my post controller under my index sub-folder inside controller folder.

I want to achieve two things in my post controller.
 1. Save data to database [Achieved]
 2. Send an email [Not getting the right way to do it]

I am using below code for sending email.

```
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('hello_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->addTo($to)
                    ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
```

But transportBuilder is not working for me. Please help me with below things

1. Which class should I extend in my controller?
2. How to write my constructor so that it can manage dependencies?

Comment: Did you got answer for this?